# jupyter Notebook cannot read head of csv file correctly

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, data-science

i just start learning Data Analytics, and trying to understand step by step cleaning the data, I have a example data from freeCodeCamp
https://github.com/ine-rmotr-curriculum/FreeCodeCamp-Pandas-Real-Life-Example
what I confused is in the "data/sales_data.csv" I try to read data in jupyter, but why jupyter cannot read my data properly(head of column renamed accidentally) , this is what jupyter shown on lab
[image]
[image]

and this is the data should look like before I upload it in jupyter
[image]

anyone can help me with this problem, I try other csv file and doesn't see this problem

Comment: Seems to be a problem in your environment. Works fine for me.

Comment: You should post:  (1) the code you used to read the csv, (2) the first handful of line of the csv file as a code snippet (not a picture), and (3) what the outcome was, also as a code snippet.  Avoid pictures of stuff.  It is near impossible to help unless you provide the necessary pieces to re-create the problem

Comment: @AirSquid sorry but i cannot show the code I used, because I'm not yet write the code, I just open the csv file in jupter, then I saw difference data with my local one

Comment: @DmitryMesserman any clue which part I should check about the environment? because I try other csv file, and its works fine to me

Comment: It may be related to line endings: they are different between DOS and UNIX.

Comment: If the issue is different, then try to find out which particular character in the file causes the issue. There is also a chance that files get corrupted when downloading. Try to open it using some other application.

Comment: Are you using Pyodide-based JupyterLite? See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75619010/8508004).

Answer (score 0):

I have faced this problem. Jupyter does not upload the CSV file correctly. What you need to do is :

1. Create a new file in JupyterLab
2. Rename it to Whatever you would like "---.csv"
3. Open the file in the editor in JupyterLab
4. Open your original CSV file in a notepad
5. Copy the contents from your original CSV in the Jupyter editor of your new file

Worked for me.