# Some data seem to be missing when I upload the csv file to Jupyter Notebook

Tags: jupyter-notebook, jupyter-lab

Thank you for clicking in here and take a look at my problem.

So I was trying to upload a csv file (1.31 MB) to JupyterLite. [(what it looks like on my comupter)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cf58D.png)
When I open it locally with Excel, it shows that there are 2000 rows of data. I dragged and dropped the file into JupyterLite and opened it there but there were only 472 rows. I checked the size and it was only 323 kB. [(This is what it looks like on the notebook.)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qBOTY.png) I looked more carefully and found out that only the last 472 rows were there.

So where did the rest go?

[Here is when I tried to load the data on the notebook.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hVRl4.png)

[Here is when I load the data locally using Pycharm.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wovu3.png)

Note the difference in row and column number but I did not make any change to the csv file.

So what did I do wrong? Thank you for your help.

I tried different upload method. And tried to export another csv file.
It seemed to work fine when I had only 300 rows of data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**IMPORTANT UPDATE**: [As of March 29, 2023](https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/jupyterlite-jupyter-webassembly-python/9939/4#file-uploads-from-1mb-scroll-to-50mb-file_cabinet-2), this should no longer be an issue if you use JupyterLite version 0.1.0b22 and beyond. "The effective ceiling is now much closer to some of the limitations of the browser, with files up to 50mb."

---

You didn't do anything wrong. It is a known issue, see [the issue report 'Can't upload CSV files > 1MB to Jupyterlite file system by drag and drop'](https://github.com/jupyterlite/jupyterlite/issues/741).
JupyterLite is undergoing a lot of development and still in the very experimental stage. As clearly indicated in text under 'Status' [at the JupyterLite main page](https://jupyterlite.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) and highlighted by the 'charged' symbols. As well as being spelled out with caution symbols to highlight at [the Try Jupyter page](https://jupyter.org/try).

If you want to work in JupyterLab wihtout touching your local system, yet with a typical, full python kernel on a temporary remote system that doesn't require logging in you still can. It is spelled out [here](https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/jupiterlab-input-function-not-working/17951/4?u=fomightez). I'll summarize:

To specify to use launches via MyBinder.org with full python kernel:
Go [here](https://github.com/binder-examples/requirements#python-environment-with-a-requirementstxt) and press '`launch binder`'. You'll get a temporary session on a remote computer without logging in. Using configuration files you can even control what is already installed, see [here](https://mybinder.readthedocs.io/en/latest/using/config_files.html). Keep in mind the sessions are temporary and will time out with inactivity. And so be sure to download anything useful you make back to your local machine promptly. You can drag-and-drop from your local machine into the left side browser panel when you start a new session to pick up again later.

Comment: I see. Thank you so much. This has been bugging me for the whole day.
I split it into two csv and uploaded them separately, then I concatenate them together. It is working fine now! Thanks again.